# maven war plugin classifier with different dependencies

Tags: maven, build, dependencies, war, classification

Following setup: I got a web project and 2 overlays of it. Therefore I got 3 different war files. Now there is a default configuration(beans, override property files, web.xml) which is used in production BUT also for testing purposes. As there are sometimes, when programming a new feature and a configuration value is set for testing purposes, values forgotten, it reaches the prod environment and that is BAD.

Now we try to get one or better two configuration projects. One for holding all default values and the other for testing. The idea was to create an additional war file for each of the 3 web projects which uses a classifier.

So there should be for example a myapp.config artifact holding all default values and a myapp.war file, and a myapp.config.dev artifact which is in the myapp-dev.war file.

As I am not yet used to maven i googled a lot round the internet how this is to achieve with the maven war plugin or maven warpath plugin but I did not find a solution. Moreover I don't know if this is the right way to implement this "feature".

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build different artifacts for different environments.  Ideally you want to deploy the same war to prod as has been tested in the test environment. Otherwise you will get bugs the testers didn't find-- why, because a bug in the build made the prod war slightly different than the test war, etc.

People usually place environment specific configuration into as few files as possible.  Ideally just one file, and have several copies of that:

```
db-config-dev.properties
db-config-test.properties
```

Then do something like add a system property to the app server startup in all environemnts:

```
-Dcom.company.environment=test
```

Finally the one *single* war behaves the same way in all environments: it loads and uses db-config-${com.company.environment}.properties